# Identify table data is retrieved from

Tags: t-sql, union, inner-join

I have a typical question with a twist.

I need to modify the following T SQL query.   Currently it only looks in one table for information.   I need to look into two tables with identical columns for information.  One table contains current employees and one contains former employees

```
SELECT t.net_Id
      ,e.fname
      ,e.lname
FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
    join view_employee e 
        on e.net_id = t.net_id
where trackingid = @trackingId
and empType = @empType
```

What I was thinking of doing is using a union to look in both.   An employee will either appear in one table or the other, it will never be in both.

```
SELECT t.net_Id
      ,e.fname
      ,e.lname
FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
    JOIN view_employee e
        ON e.net_id = t.net_id
WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
AND empType = @empType
union 
SELECT t.net_Id
      ,fe.fname
      ,fe.lname
FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
      JOIN view_employee fe 
             ON fe.net_id = t.net_id
WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
AND empType = @empType
```

However here is the twist,  I need to know if the person/s returned are current or former employees.  Is there a way to add a column to the returned table that has a 1 if its a current employee or 0 if its a former employee?  Each trackingId can potentially contain both types of employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constant column to each `SELECT` clause - you can alias it:

```
SELECT t.net_Id
      ,e.fname
      ,e.lname
      ,'Current' AS Type
FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
    JOIN view_employee e
        ON e.net_id = t.net_id
WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
AND empType = @empType
union 
SELECT t.net_Id
      ,fe.fname
      ,fe.lname
      ,'Former'
FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
      JOIN view_formerEmployee fe 
             ON fe.net_id = t.net_id
WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
AND empType = @empType
```

Comment: when I add the 'Type' line I get back twice as many results.   One set with Current and one with former that are identical

Comment: @Mike - That's very strange. Did you also add the `'Former'` line?

Comment: I found the mistake.  when I put the code up i forgot to make the second view 'view_formerEmployee fe"   The way you wrote it works without my typo.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight, you have two tables, one has current employees one has former employees?  This was a bad idea already you could have had one table with a status ('Active' / 'Inactive').  In any event just add a field, like an `int`, that you want to each query

```
SELECT
 0 AS TheField,
  ....
FROM
  Table
UNION ALL
SELECT
1 AS TheField,
 ...
FROM
  table
```

Comment: I would add that instead of just active/inactive, have a field or two that show the date the employee started and finished. The finished date would be null if they were active. There are many permutations on this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, however unfortunately the tables are not mine to change.  I just have to work with what they have set up.

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort by the Status if you would like:

```
 SELECT U.* FROM
 (
  SELECT t.net_Id AS ID
      ,e.fname AS FName
      ,e.lname AS LName
      ,'Current' AS EmployStatus
  FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
      JOIN view_employee e
          ON e.net_id = t.net_id
  WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
  AND empType = @empType
  union 
  SELECT t.net_Id AS ID
      ,fe.fname AS FName
      ,fe.lname AS LName
      ,'Former' AS EmployStatus
  FROM tblTrackingEmployee t
        JOIN view_formerEmployee fe
               ON fe.net_id = t.net_id
  WHERE trackingid = @trackingId
    AND empType = @empType
) AS U
 ORDER BY U.EmployStatus
```

Comment: when I add the 'EmployStatus' line I get back twice as many results.   One set with Current and one with former that are identical

Comment: Your tables are the same (tblTrackingEmployee) in both SELECTS.  I don't know the table of "Former" employees.  You need to edit your question.

Comment: I actually just found that mistake myself. with that fixed it works properly.   However I am selecting @Oded 's as the answer since he posted his solution first.   I really appreciate everyone's fast responses!

Comment: @Mike, No problem.  I updated my answer anyway with the Former employee table in the second select.